# Passing struct pointer in c

Tags: c, pointers, struct

i'm trying to pass a struct pointer as an argument. Here is my code:

```
void userInput(struct record **rec);

struct record{
    char Name[100];
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {      
    struct record *rec = NULL;
    userInput(&rec); 

    return 0;
}

void userInput(struct record **rec){
    
}
```

However, it does not work, i get following error:

```
main.c:25:6: error: conflicting types for ‘userInput’
   25 | void userInput(struct record **rec){
      |      ^~~~~~~~~
main.c:12:6: note: previous declaration of ‘userInput’ was here
   12 | void userInput(struct record **employeeRec);
      |
```

Do you have any idea what the problem may be?

Thanks

Comment: You have to declare the struct before the function declaration.

Comment: Unless you're allocating memory for the record in userInput you should pass a single pointer instead of a double pointer